# Круговой индикатор прогресса с плавным заполнением по кругу цветным градиентом SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animation

Мне нужно сделать круговой индикатор прогресса с цветным градиентом вдоль линии.
 А также необходимо, чтобы концы линии круга  были округлены.
 На  изображении ниже, показано то, чего я пытаюсь достичь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код близок к цели, но не имеет градиента цвета:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/adsfdsfhdsafkhdsafjkdhafskjds/pen/OJybqza)

```js
var control = document.getElementById('control');
var progressValue = document.querySelector('.progress__value');

var RADIUS = 54;
var CIRCUMFERENCE = 2 * Math.PI * RADIUS;

function progress(value) {
    var progress = value / 100;
    var dashoffset = CIRCUMFERENCE * (1 - progress);

    console.log('progress:', value + '%', '|', 'offset:', dashoffset)

    progressValue.style.strokeDashoffset = dashoffset;
}

control.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    progress(event.target.valueAsNumber);
});

progressValue.style.strokeDasharray = CIRCUMFERENCE;

progress(60);
```

```css
.demo {
    flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 120px;
}

.progress {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.progress__meter,
.progress__value {
    fill: none;
}

.progress__meter {
    stroke: grey;
}

.progress__value {
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">  
    <svg class="progress" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
        <circle class="progress__meter" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" stroke-width="12" />
        <circle class="progress__value" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" stroke-width="12" stroke="url(#gradient)" />
    </svg>
    <input id="control" type="range" value="60" />
</div>
```

Вот так это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я попытался добавить `linear-gradient` к `stroke`, но это не дало никакого эффекта.

Я также пробовал `stroke = "url(#linearColors)"`, но это также не сработало.

```html
<div class="demo">  
  <svg class="progress" width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 120 120">
    <linearGradient id="linearColors" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#01E400"></stop>
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#FEFF01"></stop>
      <stop offset="40%" stop-color="#FF7E00"></stop>
      <stop offset="60%" stop-color="#FB0300"></stop>
      <stop offset="80%" stop-color="#9B004A"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7D0022"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <circle class="progress__meter" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" stroke-width="12" />
    <circle class="progress__value" cx="60" cy="60" r="54" stroke-width="12" stroke="url(#linearColors)" />
  </svg>
  <input id="control" type="range" value="60" />
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Circular progress indicator with a color gradient with SVGs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61363990/7394871) от участника  [@Evanss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467875/evanss).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/61363990/7394871

Comment: Это очень интересная техника решения, - разбиения окружности на маленькие кусочки, которые окрашиваются в цвета с разной степенью непрозрачности и создается полная иллюзия заполнением градиентом вдоль пути. У нас на сайте такого ещё не встречалось.

Answer (score 3):

Вместо использования градиента вы можете создать иллюзию заполнением градиентом, используя 100 кругов с разной заливкой.
 Я использую атрибут `fill-opacity`, чтобы сделать элемент полностью непрозрачным или полностью прозрачным.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const CIRCUMFERENCE = base.getTotalLength()
const UNIT = CIRCUMFERENCE / 100;
let circles=[];//the array of circles

//создайте 100 кругов с разным цветом заливки, чтобы создать иллюзию градиента
for(let i = 0; i<100; i++){
  let pos = base.getPointAtLength(i*UNIT);
  let o = {cx:pos.x,cy:pos.y,r:5.5,'fill-opacity':0,fill:`hsl(220,100%,${50 + (100-i)/2}%)`}
  circles.push(drawCircle(o, progress__value));  
}

progress();

control.addEventListener('input', progress);

function progress(){
  let val = control.valueAsNumber;
  for(let i = 0; i<circles.length; i++){
    if(i<=val){
    circles[i].setAttributeNS(null,'fill-opacity',1)    
    }else{
    circles[i].setAttributeNS(null,'fill-opacity',0)
    }
  } 
}

// функция для создания круга
function drawCircle(o, parent) {
  var circle = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'circle');
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      circle.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(circle);
  return circle;
}
```

```css
svg{border:solid}

.demo {
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 120px;
}

.progress__meter{
    fill: none;
}

.progress__meter {
    stroke: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">  
    <svg class="progress"  viewBox="-2 -2 124 124">
        <path class="progress__meter" id="base" d="M60,6A54,54 0 0 1 60,114A54,54 0 0 1 60,6z"  stroke-width="12" />
      <g id="progress__value"></g>
    </svg>
    <input id="control" type="range" value="60" />
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Circular progress indicator with a color gradient with SVGs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61403931/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>